# Cost Calculation Form returning NaN for values less than 30,000

Tags: javascript, jquery

My calculation form is returning NaN for variables with values lower than 30,000.

Fiddle here - (http://jsfiddle.net/AjkXD/)

I've searched around today but I can't find the solution. I'm new to JS. Anyone able to lend a hand please?

Here's the JS:

```
function calculateCost() {
    'use strict';
    // enter annual tuition
    var $annualTuition = parseInt($('#annual_tuition').val());
    // tuition per semester
    var semesterTuition = Math.round($annualTuition / 3);
    // total number of credits for semester
    var $semesterCredits = parseInt($('#semester_credits').val());
    // cost of a single credit
    var singleCreditCost = semesterTuition / $semesterCredits;
    // total credits for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalCredits = parseInt($('#skipped_total_credits').val());
    // total cost for class being skipped
    var skippedTotalCreditsCost = $skippedTotalCredits * singleCreditCost;
    // number of times skipped class meets per week
    var $skippedWeekDays = parseInt($('#skipping_class_meet').val());
    // from date
    var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    // to date
    var toDate = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
    // calculate number of weeks in date range (semester) using 'from / to' dates
    var skippedWeeks = Math.ceil((toDate - fromDate) / (1000 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    console.log(skippedWeeks);
    // total number of days in semester for class being skipped
    //var $skippedTotalDays = parseInt($('#skipped_total_days').val());
    var skippedTotalDays = $skippedWeekDays * skippedWeeks;
    // (total cost of class) / (total number of class days in semester) = cost of class
    var skippedSingleClassCost = skippedTotalCreditsCost / skippedTotalDays;
    return skippedSingleClassCost.toFixed(2);

}

$(function() {
    'use strict';

    $('#from').datepicker({
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function() {
            //toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });

    $('#to').datepicker({
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function() {
            //fromDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });

    $('#cost').on('click', function() {
        $('.costFigure').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#costTotal').html(calculateCost());

    });

});
```

Here's the html:

```
<form id="costForm" action="#" onsubmit="#">

                <div>
                    <label for="annual_tuition">What is your annual tuition (estimated)?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="annual_tuition" id="annual_tuition" value="tuition amount" autofocus>
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value"5000">$5,000</option>
                            <option value"10000">$10,000</option>
                            <option value"15000">$15,000</option>
                            <option value"20000">$20,000</option>
                            <option value"25000">$25,000</option>
                            <option value="30000">$30,000</option>
                            <option value="35000">$35,000</option>
                            <option value="40000">$40,000</option>
                            <option value="45000">$45,000</option>
                            <option value="50000">$50,000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="semester_credits">How many total credits are you taking this semester?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="semester_credits" id="semester_credits" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="3">3 credits</option>
                            <option value="6">6 credits</option>
                            <option value="9">9 credits</option>
                            <option value="12">12 credits</option>
                            <option value="13">13 credits</option>
                            <option value="14">14 credits</option>
                            <option value="15">15 credits</option>
                            <option value="16">16 credits</option>
                            <option value="17">17 credits</option>
                            <option value="18">18 credits</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="skipped_total_credits">How many credits is the class you skipped?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="skipped_total_credits" id="skipped_total_credits" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="3">3 credits</option>
                            <option value="6">6 credits</option>
                            <option value="9">9 credits</option>
                            <option value="12">12 credits</option>
                            <option value="13">13 credits</option>
                            <option value="14">14 credits</option>
                            <option value="15">15 credits</option>
                            <option value="16">16 credits</option>
                            <option value="17">17 credits</option>
                            <option value="18">18 credits</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="skipping_class_meet">How many times a week does the class you skipped meet?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="skipping_class_meet" id="skipping_class_meet" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="1">1 time a week</option>
                            <option value="2">2 times a week</option>
                            <option value="3">3 times a week</option>
                            <option value="4">4 times a week</option>
                            <option value="5">5 times a week</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="dateRange clearfix">
                    <label>Between what months are you enrolled in this class?</label>
                    <div style="width: 48%; float: left;">
                        <label for="from">From:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 48%; float: right;">
                        <label for="to">To:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button id="cost" type="button">Calculate</button>
                </div>

                <div class="costFigure">
                    <h1>your missed class cost you $<span id="costTotal"></span></h1>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed equals signs for those values

```
        <option value"5000">$5,000</option>
        <option value"10000">$10,000</option>
        <option value"15000">$15,000</option>
        <option value"20000">$20,000</option>
        <option value"25000">$25,000</option>
```

Updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/AjkXD/1/

Also if you'll inspect your code using developer tools (ie chrome developer tools), the inspection tools will often highlight syntax errors like that making them easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

You're missing equal signs for values less than 30000:

```
                        <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value"5000">$5,000</option>
                        <option value"10000">$10,000</option>
                        <option value"15000">$15,000</option>
                        <option value"20000">$20,000</option>
                        <option value"25000">$25,000</option>
                        <option value="30000">$30,000</option>
                        <option value="35000">$35,000</option>
                        <option value="40000">$40,000</option>
                        <option value="45000">$45,000</option>
                        <option value="50000">$50,000</option>
```

Put a `=` after each `value`.

Answer (score 0):

you lost a «equal» symbol in value attribute :)

replace this:

```
<option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
<option value"5000">$5,000</option>
<option value"10000">$10,000</option>
<option value"15000">$15,000</option>
<option value"20000">$20,000</option>
<option value"25000">$25,000</option>
<option value="30000">$30,000</option>
```

to this:

```
<option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="5000">$5,000</option>
<option value="10000">$10,000</option>
<option value="15000">$15,000</option>
<option value="20000">$20,000</option>
<option value="25000">$25,000</option>
<option value="30000">$30,000</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a goofball! I was missing the '=' sign in the  elements doh!